# Can you do Log Shipping from Production non-Temporal to Data Lake Temporal setup Table?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, temporal-tables

Can you do log-shipping from a table in production without temporal tables to a secondary that has temporal tables setup?

Details:

We want a frozen nightly / yesterdays-data-only data-lake. And we would like it to be historical. Without production dealing with this historical footprint.

Comment: If I'm following you, then you should note that the temporal tables (whether set up at the system level, or maintained manually) will only include changes *from one day to the next*. Any changes that happen during the course of the day would *not* be tracked. You probably realize this, but it seemed worth noting just in case.

Comment: That would be desired... I was worried I would need a second process to accomplish that. Good to note!

Comment: You wouldn't be able to turn on system versioning on the log shipped copy of the database. So, no, you wouldn't be able to do this with the built-in temporal tables feature introduced in SQL Server 2016. You could do it manually, of course, in another database - after the restore to the log shipped copy, you could then pull that new data and import it an existing table with new timestamps, Like someone else mentioned, though, these would be snapshots that reflect restore time of the entire database, not actual transaction times of individual rows.